# Is there a way to stop Android messages from network providers?

Tags: system, sim-card, kernel, mobile-network, google-messages

I receive ads from my network provider via Android pop-ups:

[image]

Is there a way to disable it?

These messages are extremely annoying,
I woke up last night due to the brightness of the screen, as these messages causes a permanent screen brightens until an action is taken. Another side effect is that it draines the battery and heats the phone up.

Also what is this type of android messages called, so I can communicate with my network provider?

Device: Samsung Galaxy Note 9

Android version: 10

...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The SIM card is actually a tiny computer owned by your mobile network provider and your MNO also has full remote access to the SIM card and can send messages to address installed applications (we are still on the SIM card!). These applications can communicate with the phone, I would assume using the SIM toolkit system. There should be an app of that name on your phone. Unfortunately the SIM toolkit Android app can't be disabled so it is unknown if not having that app would stop these messages.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't find any helpful settings in the SIM toolkit app

Comment: Your answer helped me know the name of these messages thus better search, they are called "flash messages", and many operators provide an option to disable these messages from the SIM toolkit app. This option is not provided by my operator (Vodafone Egypt)

Comment: If it helps, I called my carrier and they disabled those irritating flash messages//Obviously, it depends on them